Derived Mosaic Dataset - 'mosaic dataset item references files that are inaccessible'
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.2 and
ArcGIS Server 10.9.1.
I have several mosaic datasets with imagery with overviews built. I want to add them to a derived mosaic to publish as an image service. The source rasters are TIF.
I run 'Add Rasters to Mosaic Dataset' - this works fine when I use 'Raster Type' as 'Table/Raster Catalog'. However all the layers, including overviews end up in the derived MD. This isn't ideal, as it clutters the table and makes navigating the service more difficult. I can publish this as an image service successfully however.
When I use 'Raster Type' as 'Raster Dataset', the resulting derived MD behaves perfectly (as a single row in the table) however on running 'Analyze Mosaic Dataset' I get the warning 'The mosaic dataset references files that are inaccessible'. Publishing an image service will work, however it won't automatically start and will give me an error in ArcGIS Server Manager ('Invalid input data source path') if I try and force it.
I have tried using UNC and mapped Drives for the paths with no difference.
Is there a way to get a derived mosaic dataset with a single row for each child mosaic dataset including overviews?
I swear I used to get them to behave this way in a previous role a while ago.
